# Issue loading serialized json objects back

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I wrote some data to a file using json.dumps. I'm now trying to read this data in another tool using json.load and json.loads and getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./compute_avg_cpu_util.py", line 16, in <module>
    data = json.loads(line.rstrip())
  File "/usr/local/python-2.76/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/python-2.76/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/python-2.76/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Here are two lines of sample data:

```
tail -2 file.dat | cat -vet

{"sample": 309896986, "data": {"value": 2}, "samples": 319049477, "startTime": "20151213T00:01:47"}    
{"sample": 309896987, "data": {"value": 2}, "samples": 319049477, "startTime": "20151213T00:01:48"}
```

Here is my code (now):

```
for file in files.split(","):
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        data = None
        for line in f:
            if not line.startswith("{"):
                continue
            data = json.loads(line)
```

I may have written these data files incorrectly by doing this (this data is coming from a REST api call to a storage device):

```
for sample in result.getdata()['data']:
    sys.stdout.write("%s\n" % json.dumps(sample))
```

Comment: `data  = json.load(open(filename, 'rb'))`

Comment: It's possible that one line is malformed - you might want to print the file name and line number as you process them to see where it actually raises this exception.

Comment: It would be better to catch exceptions because it will potentially let you know there's something wrong with your file (and what/where). Your updated code just silently ignores any garbage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1）try to catch any Exceptions:

```
  try:
    data = json.loads(line.rstrip())
  except ValueError as ve:
    print "ERROR: {0} cannot be parsed, exception message:{1}".format(line, ve)
    continue
```

2)
I also tested your json sample, it works:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('{"sample": 309896986, "data": {"value": 2}, "samples": 319049477, "startTime": "20151213T00:01:47"}')
{u'sample': 309896986, u'data': {u'value': 2}, u'startTime': u'20151213T00:01:47', u'samples': 319049477}
```

I saved your sample json lines into `sample.csv` and parse it correctly by following code:
import json

```
with open("sample.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        data = json.loads(line.rstrip())
        print(data)
```

My guessing is that it may have some unformatted lines in your files. You need to debug your lines.

Comment: You should follow your own advice by changing `for line in f.readlines():` to `for line in f:`

Comment: Still getting the same error. I updated my snippet above to what I'm working with now -- getting exact same error.

Comment: There's no need to change the `with open(file) as f:`, the default is `"r"` (read) mode.

Comment: @BenH  try adding `try except` to catch exceptions and see which line cannot be parsed, is the first line of your file is blank?

Comment: Changing the `for line in f.readlines():` to `for line in f:` really only affects whether the file is read entirely into memory first or not. In either case each line will be processed iteratively one at a time. The real problem is that in general you can't parse a properly formatted JSON file line-by-line.

Comment: Ok I'm an idiot. Forgot had some debug code that wrote something to the first 2 lines of each file:  cpu.utilization
     2 /api/analytics/v1/datasets/cpu.utilization/data?start=20151206T00:00:00&seconds=604800

Comment: see my advice 1)   use `try except` with `continue` to ignore those unformatted lines.

Comment: Yea normally I would use try/except but this was a quick and dirty one time script to generate a one-off report. Should have taken the time to use a try block and would have immediately noticed my debug output. Thx everyone for the help.